# Where are the hadoop-examples* and hadoop-test* jars in Cloudera CDH?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I am looking for the jar files to be able to run the hadoop jobs associated with the examples and test jars. In the past they were under /usr/lib/hadoop, but apparently no longer.  Pointers appreciated.

**Note**: this question was originally for CDH4.2. But some answers include info for later versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found them under /usr/local/lib as follows (replace 4.2.1 with specific cloudera version you are using):

mrv1: /usr/local/lib/hadoop_mr1/hadoop-examples-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.1.jar
mrv2: /usr/local/lib/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.0.0-cdh4.2.1.jar

So we can run it as: hadoop jar /usr/local/lib/hadoop_mr1/hadoop-examples-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.1.jar pi 500 40

Comment: In hadoop-2.6.0 they are in `/usr/local//hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar`, just without `lib`.

Answer (score 5):

```
find / -name hadoop-mapreduce-examples*.jar
```

/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.0.0-cdh4.7.0.jar

/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar

Answer (score 4):

On my single-node Hadoop 2.3.0-cdh5.0.2 setup on CentOS release 6.5 (Final) I found the mapred examples at /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.3.0-cdh5.0.3.jar (symlinked from /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar). Via http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_tips_guidelines.html .

Answer (score 1):

As other person mentioned, depending on the Operating System and installer, the install location can be configured. For CDH4 on RHEL, using the cloudera manager as Installer, the examples and test jars can be found in the following locations.

`/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.0-1.cdh4.2.0.p0.10/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar`

```
'/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.0-1.cdh4.2.0.p0.10/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.2.0-tests.jar'
```

Answer (score 0):

So they moved things around based on the hadoop directory changes in the new API.

```
${CDH4_DIR}/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar
${CDH4_DIR}/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-*-tests.jar
```

but the directory where most of the jar files are now located is in

```
${CDH4_DIR}/share/hadoop/
```

Comment: pls provide the fully qualified path instead of relative. thx!

Comment: Sorry, Im not sure I really can.  I updated my answer to include where I start from, but I download the cloudera packages and place the jars where I want.  I don't use any sort of installer.

Answer (score 0):

I issue the find command in my environment. `Red Hat Linux. Hadoop 2.5.0`

> find / -name *examples*.jar
>   /app/hadoop-2.5.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.0-sources.jar
>   /app/hadoop-2.5.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.0-test-sources.jar

**/app/hadoop-2.5.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.0.jar**

/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/demo/jpda/examples.jar